# webfont displayed screwy on pc

Tags: cross-platform, webfonts

Wondering if anyone has come across this before. The first image is how it displays on MS platforms and is incorrect, the 2nd is how it displays on apple and is correct.

[image: This is what it looks like on PCs]

[image: And this is what it should look like, displays correctly on apple comps]

Thanks, for any help!

Comment: Lot of people having issue with fonts ...on different platform..

Answer (score 0):

Font rendering differs across webbrowsers and platforms. There are many ways to specifically target those different enviroments.

Looking at the images it seems that the aliasing gives a less 'thight' result for this font at the size. You could try a slightly different size in your MS enviroment for better results.